# Loss of internal memory after rooting HCL ME V1

Tags: rooting, internal-storage

I have HCL ME V1 tablet with android 4.0(Icecream Sandwich) OS. It has 4GB of internal SD memory and 1GB DDR3 RAM. When I connect the device to the PC in storage mode, it shows the 4GB SD memory; which is fine, I belief.

Since this device didn’t come with Google play store, I rooted it with “Android Commander” and installed Google play store and Google services. Then I reset the tablet to factory setting.
After resetting, when I connect it to pc it shows me total size of internal SD as 1.5GB out of which 900 MB approx is free.

My question is – Where did the additional 2.5GB internal storage space go ?

---

I have viewed the "Settings -> Storage" and found the storage distribution as below,

FLASH:
Total: 4 GB, Firmware 3.09 GB

DATA STORAGE:
Total: 0.91 GB, Apps 228 MB, Available 698 MB

It seems the internal SD still has, 4GB, out of which 3.09GB is eaten up by firmware. So How can it be corrected. Earlier it was much lesser.

Comment: Could you please check on the device itself: *Settings->Storage* (optionally link a screenshot if you need help intepreting that display)?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be possible that you lose your internal storage because of rooting, as firmware is your OS and drivers. Which are taking space and don't even related to rooting in any way.

Comment: It's possible that this device was lying to you originally about the storage size, and would never have let you store anything like 4GB had you tried, despite reporting that amount of memory.

Comment: In other words, as mentioned by @karan, your OS and drivers are the same after the root process!

Answer (score 0):

You can try flashing your device completely and install the lightweight generic ROM from Google.